# DP two knapsack problem, UVa Feary loading

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve UVa 10261/Ferry loading. The question is:

> Given a queue of cars (with given lengths) in a given order and a ship (of a given length) with two lanes, determine the maximum number of cars you can load on the ship. A car can't be skipped and if you can't place more cars, you finish.

Any idea or hints on solving it?  I would prefer an iterative solution.

If you wish to see the link to the problem it is [here](https://onlinejudge.org/external/102/10261.pdf).

Comment: Use top-down DP (memoization of recursive function): `boolean AssignCar(carNo, remainingRightSide, remainingLeftSide)`.  You can further improve this by swapping right and left anytime the remaining space on the right is shorter than on the left.

Comment: Can this be solved greedily as well?  I am looking at [Interval Scheduling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scheduling-in-greedy-algorithms/) algorithm #3.

Comment: @Someone Greedy method will not produce an optimal solution in all cases.